# How to Get the Frame Count of an AVI File using Java

Tags: java, avi

How can I get the number of frames in an AVI file using java (without decoding the file)? I believe there should be a way to grab that value from the header of the file, but not quite sure how. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](http://www.fastgraph.com/help/avi_header_format.html), the total number of frames is encoded at byte number 16 with a length of 4 bytes. The header starts at byte offset 32. You can find detailed information about the byte structure of the AVI header [here](http://www.alexander-noe.com/video/documentation/avi.pdf).

An implementation for easily extracting all relevant header information can be found [here](http://dev.loci.wisc.edu/trac/software/browser/trunk/loci/formats/AVIReader.java?rev=657), although I didn't try this code.

According to this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574595/parse-avi-header-java), you can also find an implementation [here](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/plugins/download/AVI_Reader.java)

On [this](http://blog.gungfu.de/archives/2009/04/13/trying-to-read-metadata-from-avi-files-in-java/) page, there are several Java projects listed that provide a way to extract the header data from an AVI file.